# Show Non English text in Angular app

Tags: angular, html

Using Angular v5 I have created an app. In one of the pages I have to show the product description in a language selected by the user - `_descriptionLang`. The description text is rendered from DB using http service.

**HTML -**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of productList">
    <td>{{item.productNo}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="_descriptionLang === 'EN'">{{item.description_en}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="_descriptionLang === 'FR'"><span lang="fr">{{item.description_fr}}</span></td>
    <td *ngIf="_descriptionLang === 'GE'"><span lang="de">{{item.description_ge}}</span></td>
    <td *ngIf="_descriptionLang === 'IT'"><span lang="it">{{item.description_it}}</span></td>
    <td *ngIf="_descriptionLang === 'RU'"><span lang="ru">{{item.description_ru}}</span></td>
    <td *ngIf="_descriptionLang === 'SP'"><span lang="es">{{item.description_sp}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

**component.ts -**

```
     searchCombinations(searchInput) {
        this.productService.getProductDetails(searchInput)
          .subscribe(response => {
            this.productList = response.records;
           });
      }
```

**Service Response JSON -**

[image: Service Response JSON]

Above code is not showing the non-english desc and I am getting blank in description column.

*Translation of description from english to selected lang is not my requirement.*

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: your condition checking works fine?

Comment: @AravindS yes... I have tested that.

Comment: for example use like this `<span [innerHTML]="item.description_fr">`

Comment: Could you also provide your components logic, and double check item.description_fr and similar variables are not returning undefined

Comment: @coder I tried `[innerHTML]`....still same result..

Comment: Added component code and response json.

Comment: could you able to provide stackblitz demo about the issue?

Comment: Everythings fine there, perhaps you are setting `_descriptionLang` wrong?

Comment: Try to remove all the ngIf attributes and see if they show up. My guess is that something is not working in the condition check.